# Project Euler 23: insight on this stackoverflow-ing program needed

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

Hi [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) fellows. I'm currently working on the [23rd problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=23) of [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/). Where I'm at atm is that my code seems right to me - not in the "good algorithm" meaning, but in the "should work" meaning - but produces a Stack memory overflow.

I do know that my algorithm isn't perfect (in particular I could certainly avoid computing such a big intermediate result at each recursion step in my `worker` function).

Though, being in the process of learning Haskell, I'd like to understand why this code fails so miserably, in order to avoid this kind of mistakes next time.

Any insight on why this program is wrong will be appreciated.

```
import qualified Data.List as Set ((\\))

main = print $ sum $ worker abundants [1..28123]

-- Limited list of abundant numbers
abundants :: [Int]
abundants = filter (\x -> (sum (divisors x)) - x > x) [1..28123]

-- Given a positive number, returns its divisors unordered.
divisors :: Int -> [Int]
divisors x  | x > 0     =   [1..squareRoot x] >>=
                            (\y ->  if      mod x y == 0
                                    then    let d = div x y in
                                            if y == d
                                            then [y]
                                            else [y, d]
                                    else    [])
            | otherwise = []


worker :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
worker (a:[]) prev = prev Set.\\ [a + a]
worker (a:as) prev = worker as (prev Set.\\ (map ((+) a) (a:as)))


-- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Generic_number_type#squareRoot
(^!) :: Num a => a -> Int -> a
(^!) x n = x^n

squareRoot :: Int -> Int
squareRoot 0 = 0
squareRoot 1 = 1
squareRoot n =
   let twopows = iterate (^!2) 2
       (lowerRoot, lowerN) =
          last $ takeWhile ((n>=) . snd) $ zip (1:twopows) twopows
       newtonStep x = div (x + div n x) 2
       iters = iterate newtonStep (squareRoot (div n lowerN) * lowerRoot)
       isRoot r  =  r^!2 <= n && n < (r+1)^!2
   in  head $ dropWhile (not . isRoot) iters
```

Edit: the exact error is `Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.`. Increasing the stack memory limit through `+RTS -K...` doesn't solve the problem.

Edit2: about the sqrt thing, I just copy pasted it from the link in comments. To avoid having to cast Integer to Doubles and face the rounding problems etc...

Comment: Can you post the exact error? I've never seen an actual stack overflow in Haskell. Space leak? Also, your implementation of newton's method is really confusing to me. Why aren't you using the included sqrt function?

Comment: @Josh: I edited my OP to answer you

Comment: Ok, that's a space leak. What function do you run when that happens? Usually that means you either need to memoize the function, or rewrite it to be tail recursive.

Comment: @Josh: Well it happens when I run the `:main` function which calls the `worker` loop. The `worker` recursion seems TCO-able to me, that's why I'm surprised :(

Comment: Just to try a low-hanging fruit, did you try `-O2` compilation key?

Comment: yup this error comes from an `-O2` compiled runnable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the future, it's polite to attempt a bit of minimalization on your own. For example, with a bit of playing, I was able to discover that the following program also stack-overflows (with an 8M stack):

```
main = print (worker [1..1000] [1..1000])
```

...which really nails down just what function is screwing you over. Let's take a look at `worker`:

```
worker (a:[]) prev = prev Set.\\ [a + a]
worker (a:as) prev = worker as (prev Set.\\ (map ((+) a) (a:as)))
```

Even on my first read, this function was red-flagged in my mind, because it's tail-recursive. Tail recursion in Haskell is generally not such a great idea as it is in other languages; guarded recursion (where you produce at least one constructor before recursing, or recurse some small number of times before producing a constructor) is generally better for lazy evaluation. And in fact, here, what's happening is that each recursive call to `worker` is building a deeper- and deeper-ly nested thunk in the `prev` argument. When the time comes to finally return `prev`, we have to go very deeply into a long chain of `Set.\\` calls to work out just what it was we finally have.

This problem is obfuscated slightly by the fact that the obvious strictness annotation doesn't help. Let's massage `worker` until it works. The first observation is that the first clause is completely subsumed by the second one. This is stylistic; it shouldn't affect the behavior (except on empty lists).

```
worker []     prev = prev
worker (a:as) prev = worker as (prev Set.\\ map (a+) (a:as))
```

Now, the obvious strictness annotation:

```
worker []     prev = prev
worker (a:as) prev = prev `seq` worker as (prev Set.\\ map (a+) (a:as))
```

I was surprised to discover that this still stack overflows! The sneaky thing is that `seq` on lists only evaluates far enough to learn whether the list matches either `[]` or `_:_`. The following does not stack overflow:

```
import Control.DeepSeq

worker []     prev = prev
worker (a:as) prev = prev `deepseq` worker as (prev Set.\\ map (a+) (a:as))
```

I didn't plug this final version back into the original code, but it at least works with the minimized `main` above. By the way, you might like the following implementation idea, which also stack overflows:

```
import Control.Monad

worker as bs = bs Set.\\ liftM2 (+) as as
```

but which can be fixed by using `Data.Set` instead of `Data.List`, and no strictness annotations:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Set as Set

worker as bs = toList (fromList bs Set.\\ fromList (liftM2 (+) as as))
```

Comment: This answers my questions. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The `liftM` version does not stackoverflow for me.

Comment: @is7s Be sure to add `+RTS -K8M`; newer GHCs have a floating stack size that hides deep thunks in a lot of cases. (Hence the comment at the beginning of the answer, "with an 8M stack".)

Comment: @Daniel Yes you are right. But why does it stackoverflow? `liftM2 (+) as as` produces a list of 1000000 `Int`s which should be only 4 megabytes. Am I wrong?

Comment: @is7s It shouldn't even build the whole list at once, and if it did, it wouldn't build it on the stack. My bet is that `(Data.List.\\)` tries to be a bit too lazy.

Comment: @Daniel Yes. Maybe because `(\\)` uses `foldl` not `foldl'`

Comment: @is7s That wouldn't help here, `foldl'` would just do enough to see whether it's empty yet. But the fold builds a nest of thunks, so that's bad.

Answer (score 8):

As [Daniel Wagner correctly said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9967292/1011995), the problem is that

```
worker (a:as) prev = worker as (prev Set.\\ (map ((+) a) (a:as)))
```

builds a badly nested thunk. You can avoid that and get somewhat better performance than with `deepseq` by exploiting the fact that both arguments to `worker` are sorted in this application. Thus you can get incremental output by noting that at any step everything in `prev` smaller than `2*a` cannot be the sum of two abundant numbers, so

```
worker (a:as) prev = small ++ worker as (large Set.\\ map (+ a) (a:as))
  where
    (small,large) = span (< a+a) prev
```

does better. However, it's still bad because `(\\)` cannot use the sortedness of the two lists. If you replace it with

```
minus xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys)
    = case compare x y of
        LT -> x : minus xs yys
        EQ -> minus xs ys
        GT -> minus xxs ys
minus xs _ = xs             -- originally forgot the case for one empty list
```

(or use the [data-ordlist](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-ordlist/0.4.5/doc/html/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:minus) package's version), calculating the set-difference is O(length) instead of O(length^2).

Comment: thanks for the insight, those considerations are indeed interesting :)

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I discovered [Data.List.Ordered](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-ordlist/0.4.5/doc/html/Data-List-Ordered.html), which has a bunch of functions I've been re-implementing all the time. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielWagner Nice. I abstractly knew about it, but I don't use that kind of function often enough to remember that package.

Comment: There's a mistake in either `smalls` or `small` :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I loaded it up and gave it a shot. Daniel Wagner's advice is pretty good, probably better than mine. The problem is indeed with the worker function, but I was going to suggest using Data.MemoCombinators to memoize your function instead.

Also, your divisors algorithm is kind of silly. There's a much better way to do that. It's kind of mathy and would require a lot of TeX, so here's a link to a math.stackexchange page about how to do that. The one I was talking about, was the accepted answer, though someone else gives a recursive solution that I think would run faster. (It doesn't require prime factorization.)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-proper-divisors-of-a-number

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's kind of off topic since I was specifically looking for hints about why this program fails and how to avoid the mistake beforehand next time. Those considerations are more about the algorithm (and I do know that there are other implementations of divisors, this one is fast enough for this exercise though, and the important part of the computations aren't done there, so it'd be poor optimization policy to spend time bettering this part of the program).

Comment: Hahaha sorry, Daniel beat me to the punch. I was about to write up a lengthier solution, but instead you got the random suggestions I had left over after he cleaned the question out.